# Reporting Services Export to Excel With Blank Pivot Table

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a MS Reporting Services Report that will be exported to excel. How can I export to Excel with a blank pivot table already integrated such that users do not have to create their own?

Comment: I don't think that the SSRS's Excel Renderer supports generating PivotTables.  In fact, its hard to control column merging or repeating fields for grouped values to even make it a good source for a PivotTable.  You could export to CSV and use an Excel macro to achieve something similar, but that would have its own steps.  There's some background at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create native Excel PivotTables with the SSRS Excel emitter.  There are 3rd party SSRS plugins such as [OfficeWriter](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/RS8/Working+With+PivotTables) which allegedly can do this, although I've not used any personally.